# Sorting 3 piles of numbers row by row left to right

Tags: python, list, sorting

Hey I need to sort out 3 lists in a special way after they have been mixed up and placed like in a deck row by row ([Link to the full question](http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/resources/computing/AQA-85203-SNEA3.PDF)):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[7,8,9]
```

Now the order is b, a, c and you have to place all of the numbers from left to right (I need to do this for a deck so the numbers will contain letters next to them making them a string).

Expected outcome:

- a = [4,1,7]
- b = [5,2,8]
- c = [6,3,9]

*Note the lists that I am working on contain more than 3 values in them

Comment: how can your list contain more than 3 values? what outcome do you expect if your lists have 4 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `zip` them:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[4,5,6]
>>> c=[7,8,9]

>>> a, b, c = map(list, zip(b, a, c))  # in the order specified: b, a, c

>>> a
[4, 1, 7]
>>> b
[5, 2, 8]
>>> c
[6, 3, 9]
```

It would also work with (but that changes the lists in-place):

```
>>> a[:], b[:], c[:] = zip(b, a, c)
```

Instead of the `map(list, ...)`.

---

In case you have more values and want to distribute them:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=[5,6,7,8]
>>> c=[9,10,11,12]

>>> tmp = b + a + c   # concatenate them in the order

>>> # distribute them: every third element, starting with 0 (a), 1 (b) and 2 (c)
>>> a, b, c = tmp[::3], tmp[1::3], tmp[2::3]  

>>> a
[5, 8, 3, 10]
>>> b 
[6, 1, 4, 11]
>>> c
[7, 2, 9, 12]
```

Comment: So sorry its my first time doing this so I probably should of mentioned that my 3 lists have 7 values or 'cards' each so your code just comes up with a Value Error: too many values to unpack (expected 3). If you got any suggestions for how I could fix it I would greatly appreciate it thank you.

Comment: @Xotsu not sure what you mean, could you ask a new question (or edit this one - but a new question will be more likely to attract more answers) with the **real** inputs and expected outcomes?

Comment: @Xotsu I'm not sure if that's what you need but I included another approach.

Comment: What you done was fine but it only worked on 3 values in each of the 3 lists my problem is that I have 3 lists with 7 values in each of them so when I run the program it comes up with an error

Comment: @Xotsu Did you check the last approach?

Comment: Yes I have just done it and it works, thank you so much I've been trying to figure this out for 6 hours now...

Comment: @Xotsu No problem, if it finally solved your issue you could [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Comment: I have but it says I need at least 15 reputation for it to show up publicly. How do I increase it?

Comment: @Xotsu Accepting (the checkmark below the arrays) doesn't require any reputation. Upvoting requires 15 reputation and downvoting 125. The link (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) shows where you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once the selected pile has been picked, you need to put the selected pile in the middle of the other two piles. One option would be just to combine the three different pile lists into one list, with the chosen pile in the middle.

```
if pile == 1: NewCards = Pile2 + Pile1 + Pile3
elif pile == 2: NewCards = Pile1 + Pile2 + Pile3
else: NewCards = Pile1 + Pile3 + Pile2
```

EDIT:
Okay, so you need to deal out the combination of the cards into 3 piles. You can loop through each of the decks, and deal them out. Make sure the right deck is in the middle! (In this case I'll use deck 2).

```
 # create three empty temporary lists
 temp = [[],[],[]]
 cardnum = 0

 # loop through the 3 decks
 for i in range(3):
     if i == 0: deck = partA
     elif i == 1: deck = partB
     else: deck = partC

     # loop through the cards in the decks
     for card in deck:
         i = cardnum % 3 # mod 3 to split the cards among the decks
         temp[i] += card
         cardnum += 1

# update the decks now
partA = temp[0]
partB = temp[1]
partC = temp[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but I need the piles to be combined in a certain way, sorry I didn't properly phrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm .... an interesting problem :P

I am going to do some thing which i hate when people do to me... post code...
See if there is something here that helps you.

HINT HINT: Have a look at the get_order function.

```
from itertools import product, izip_longest
import random

def grouped(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *[iter(iterable)] * n)

def get_order(selected, seq=[0,1,2]):
    seq = [i for i in seq if i!=selected]
    seq.insert(len(seq)/2, selected)
    return seq


deck = ['-'.join(card) for card in product('c h d s'.split(), 'a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 j q k'.split())]
plycards= random.sample(deck,21)

piles = [[],[],[]]
for idx, i in enumerate(grouped(plycards, 3)):
    for idx, item in enumerate(i):
        piles[idx].append(item)
    print (i)

for j in range(0,3):
    # Combine again 
    plycards = []
    for i in get_order(int(raw_input('Which pile? '))-1):
        plycards += piles[i]
    print ('-------------')
    piles = [[],[],[]]
    for idx, i in enumerate(grouped(plycards, 3)):
        for jdx, item in enumerate(i):
            piles[jdx].append(item)
        print (i)

print ("You selected card :'{}'".format(plycards[10])
```